# How to fix 'Failed to connect to MySQL: Connection refused' when trying to connect to a server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, digital-ocean

This is for a school project so i don't really have control over the server. The Database is running on DigitalOcean. My code works perfectly when running it on a Heroku or locally (both connect to the DigitalOcean instance perfectly). But when i upload it to the school server this is the error message it get: Failed to connect to MySQL: Connection refused.

PHP version of the school server: 5.6.24-0+deb8u1
Locally i'm running PHP 7.2.8.

I have already checked:

- mysqli is present and seems to be active when running phpinfo(); on the school server.

```
$credentials = $this->credentials;

$con = new mysqli($credentials["server"], $credentials["user"], $credentials["password"], $credentials["db_name"]);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    var_dump($con);
}
```

Now, i have a suspicion it doesn't work because of the older PHP version but i cant find any evidence that i'm doing smth not like it should be done in php 5.6 or that my syntax would be wrong.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Is your database on a remote server, different than the school server? If so, you may need to whitelist the IP from your school server

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes. The mySQL database is running DigitalOcean.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about DigitalOcean, but I found this thread that may be related https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-remote-access - my keywords were "digitalocean remote access"

Comment: Make sure that you can connect to the mysql database first from the command line. `mysql -h<host> -u<user>` If that fails with the same error message you want to be sure you can telnet to the mysql server `telnet <hostname> 3306` If that also fails (I am assuming that it will) you need to troubleshoot the network connection to that mysql server. Make sure that `bind-address` is set to the public ip address of the machine it is hosted on in my.conf. Check that no firewalls (iptables or ufw) are blocking mysql's port. One piece of advice: Don't make your MySQL server public if at all possible.